# VenoBox (responsive jQuery lightbox) video not loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

1. I am using a template from ThemeForest which is located [here](https://themeforest.net/item/signature-multipurpose-many-concept-portfolio/12849711).
2. The jQuery plugin included in the template is called VenoBox. Documentation can be located [here](http://veno.es/venobox/).

I have followed the steps from the documentation, referencing the correct CSS on my website which can be viewed [here](http://timothymaryon.com/). I have checked the console and there are no errors. When I click on the link to the video lightbox, the lightbox appears, but the video doesn't load.

**CSS:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/isotope.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/venobox.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/sinister.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/slimmenu.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/main.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/main-bg.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/main-responsive.css">  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/lightbox.css">
```

**HTML:**

```
<!-- start : works-item -->
              <div class="works-item signature-adler ImageWrapper works-item-one-half zoom logos">
                      <img data-no-retina alt="" title="" class="img-responsive" src="images/works/04.jpg"/>
                      <a  class="venobox" data-gall="portfolio-gallery" data-vbtype="video" data-autoplay="true" href="https://vimeo.com/221800817">
                          <div class="works-item-inner ImageOverlayHe">
                            <p class="valign text-center"><span class="white font3">SCOPE</span></p>
                          </div>
                      </a>
              </div>
              <!-- end : works-item -->
```

**JS/jQuery:**

```
<script src="javascripts/libs/common.js"></script>
    <script src="javascripts/libs/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="javascripts/custom/main.js"></script>
    <script src="javascripts/custom/lightbox.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.venobox').venobox(); 
});</script>
```

Comment: Assuming the lightbox is opened from the 'scope' tab, then the error is due to CORB as can be seen in the console: `Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response https://vimeo.com/221800817 with MIME type text/html. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.`

Comment: Thanks @RoryMcCrossan I can see that error now, not sure why it wasn't showing a few mins ago! I have tried with various video URLs now - YouTube etc. with no luck. Reading the info on that URL you supplied it looks like it blocks sensitive data?!

Comment: That's correct. Try checking Vimeo's integration docs as there may be another URL you can use which is intended for third party embedding.

Comment: The URL for embedding is the same as I've used, already tried that unfortunately! I can't say I've ever seen this type of warning before, and it's strange that it does it with all video URLs regardless of their source.